# How to get azure storage container access policy details

Tags: azure, storage

How to get azure storage container access policy details

I have more then 300 storage account in single subscription and more then 1000 container and now i want to get all container access policy expiry date.

Comment: Get Container ACL.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-container-acl

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get access policies for all blob containers in a single call. You will need to get access policy details for each blob container separately.

Here's the approach you would need to take:

1. List storage accounts in your Azure Subscription.
2. For each storage account, get the account key.
3. Using storage SDK, list the blob containers in a storage account.
4. For each blob container, get the access policy details.

Comment: Get-AzStorageAccount | Get-AzStorageContainer | Get-AzStorageContainerStoredAccessPolicy using this command i can get access policy for list of access policy but its coming with only access policy i need to add storage account name so we can identify storage account